# skipping unknown options without throwing with boost program options

Tags: c++, boost-program-options

These days I am playing with Boost program options for reading INI files.

The code I have throws an exception once in the file there is a line with an unknown option.
Do you know whether is possible and how to let the code below read the whole file? I want to skip the unknown options without throwing so that I can read all possible values.
Thanks a lot
AFG

```
 namespace pod = boost::program_options;
 pod::options_description options("Options");
 std::string myArgValue;
 options.add_options()     

      ("SECT_A.Option_A", 
           pod::value<int>()->default_value(1), 
           "xxx")

      ("SECT_B.Option_B", 
           pod::value<std::string>(&myArgValue),
           "xxx")
 ;

 pod::variables_map vm;
 pod::store( pod::parse_config_file( s, options ) , vm);
 pod::notify( vm );
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yip: `allow_unregistered()`, have a look at:

http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_45_0/doc/html/program_options/howto.html#id2075177

Comment: CAn you help me? It doesn't compile. I update my code as the following
     pod::store( pod::parse_config_file( s, options ).allow_unregistered(),  vm);
but it doesn't compile.

Comment: Hi Again. I found how to do that in my specific case.
parse_config_file has a third optioanl value called "allow_unregistered" that is set to 'false' as default.
I set to 'true' and I don't have exceptions any more.